# Installation error ImageMagick on Linux CentOS release 6.8

Tags: php, linux, centos, imagemagick, centos6.8

for the Joomla component to work, I need the ImageMagick package, which I decided to install under this instruction https://codebeer.ru/ustanovka-imagemagick-v-centos-7/

But during the installation after the command `yum install gcc php-devel php-pear`

Received an Error:

> php71w-common conflicts with php-common-5.3.3-49.el6.x86_64

Version of my Linux CentOS 6.8

It is required to correctly install the package and the extension for PHP ImageMagic.

All installation instructions have already tried, unfortunately the error does not pass, but the package is not installed, I'm new to setting up servers, so I ask for help.

Comment: Are you using php7.1?

Comment: yes I using php 7.1

Answer (score 0):

- As you should always do, backup your server/data before making any possible breaking changes *

I'm assuming you're using php71 .. webtatic from the 'w' suffix. ( Same flavor I personally use )

** ***Unless you're actively using PHP5.x still*** **, just yum remove the conflicting PHP5 package

```
yum remove php-common
```

Then re-yum your imagick package and you should be all good.